# How to access Git repository in jenkins on Docker

Tags: git, docker, jenkins, private-key

I have a Docker container created from the official Jenkins image.
I created a job which pulls the sources from a remote Git repository. The user is authenticated with an ssh key.

I run Docker using the Docker toolbox for Windows and use Kitematic for managing my container.
I bound /var/jenkins_home to a directory on my Windows machine to persist the Jenkins configuration and jobs.

When I run a job, I always get this error:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0555 for 
'/var/jenkins_home/workspace/test@tmp/ssh12345.key' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
```

It seems that Jenkins stores the private key temporarily in a file which is under /var/jenkins_home. The permissions of that file are `-r-xr-xr-x`

But I cannot change them.

```
chmod 600 ssh12345.key
```

has no effect. Probably because it is under the mounted directory.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use volumes `/home/jenkins` only with this workaround in Powershell:

```
$Env:COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But how do I need to use it? Can I set it as environment variable in Kitematic? Or do I need to define it in the CLI before running the container?

Comment: Switch to Linux containers. Next set $Env:COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1 and after it you should use docker-compset to run jenkins in docker where         volumes:
            - /home/jenkins:/home/jenkins